# Firebase Phone Authentication Using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm here to ask about how to Authenticate the user using Phone Number in Firebase.

I've tried using Email and Password, and working great with Firebase.Auth NUGET.
But i can't find the syntax if the input just Phone Number and Password.
Is anyone know how to make Phone Authentication in ASP.NET MVC? or give some document link that i can follow.

Comment: i have found the answer. if you have same problem just see the following url :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jYIIwm6IeI

Thanks
Regard

Lazu